# "Cut" data out within the graph

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am trying to find an existing script that would allow me to cut parts of the graph.

Example : http://prntscr.com/b21s15

User would click on the graph and select an area to mark out, marked out area will be in grey colour.

Idea is that when someone is to create an image or export data the "greyed out" area will not be present.